# knex.js: Table Infered TypeScript types

Tags: typescript, knex.js

I am playing with knex.js and I want to try TypeScript support for my tables.

Following this http://knexjs.org/#typescript-support

I have tried to add this simple snippet everywhere with no results.

```js
declare module 'knex/types/tables' {
 interface Tables {
    // This is same as specifying `knex<User>('users')`
    users: { id: string, name: string };
}
```

I've tried:

- on top of the same file that perform query
- on a `types.d.ts` file added to `compilerOptions.types` in `tsconfig.json`

Did anyone get to make it work? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this to work with the following:

Create a directory for your custom types, (i did `src/@types`) an add all your `.d.ts` (also should work with standar `.ts`)

Then, in your `tsconfig.ts` add the following inside `compilerOptions`

```
"typeRoots": ["./nodemodules/@types", "./src/@types"]
```

then inside your custom types directory create you declaration file for knex Tables, in my case  `src/@types/index.d.ts`

```
import { knex } from 'knex';

import { User } from 'path/to/your/interfaces'

declare module 'knex/types/tables' {      
  interface Tables {
    users: User;
    users_composite: Knex.CompositeTableType<
      User,
      Pick<User, 'name'> & Partial<Pick<User, 'created_at' | 'updated_at'>>,
      Partial<Omit<User, 'id'>>
    >;
  }
}
```

**Note:** this is just the same example from official knex, please [see](https://knexjs.org/#typescript-support) for more information

Then you can use infered types:

```
const user = await db.from('users').first() // User || undefined
const user = await db.table('users').first() // User || undefined
```

...Just for make it clear my `db` variable is just exported somewhere else as `knex({...})`, [see](https://knexjs.org/#Installation-client)